# "Requested conversion is not supported" when selecting bigquery table using linked server is SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, google-bigquery, data-conversion, simba

I'm trying to select data from Bigquery to SQL Server, using a linked server with ODBC with [Simba driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/).

Environment:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 64 bit
- Simba Driver 64 bit

Some datatypes are returned ok (INTEGER, TIMESTAMP, BOOLEAN) but STRING does not get returned.

The error is:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "BQ" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported."

And this is the query:

```
select <column_name> 
from [linked_server].[projectId].[dataset].[table]
```

I tried configuring the Server Options~> Collation Compatible to True, but still the same. 
like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775186/requested-conversion-is-not-supported-using-a-linked-server-and-odbc)

Comment: I guess the problem is length/datatype. I would create view on remote site with explicit cast `CAST(field as varchar(4000))` and try to `select from [linked_server].[projectId].[dataset].[view_name]`

Comment: Thanks @lad2025. The problem is that there is no varchar in BiqQuery, nor TEXT (which I found as a possible solution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating the ODBC connection, under Advanced Options, there is a field named "Default String Column Length". MSSQL can't handle over 8000 characters but the initial value over there is 65535. Changing it to 4000, for example, solved the issue.

[Advanced Options](https://ibb.co/d4uJec)

Comment: huge find.  thank you so much for posting your answer.

Comment: saved lot of headache. thanks